# List of lists (or numpy array): extracting data via SQL-like methods?

Tags: python, sql, numpy, search, data-structures

The problem: given a (large) Python list-of-lists, or, semi-equivalently, a numpy array, extract information from the array in a SQL-like manner, i.e., as if the array were a database.

For example: given a 4-column by (large) N-row array, extract the rows where the first column is equal to X. In SQL this would be:

`SELECT * FROM array WHERE col_1_id = X`

In Python, however... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

---

An attempt to make the issue clearer:

The array in question holds in each sublist/row `[M, a^2, b^2, c^2`], where `M` is the sum of the squares. The list contains millions of entries, and M ranges from ~100 to ~10^6.

The desire is to extract from this data only the rows for which at least 8 different rows have the same sum. Naively we can do this with a loop:

```
Output = []
    for i in [0..10^6]:
    newarray = []
    for row in array:
        if row[0] == i:
            newarray.append(row)
    if len(newarray) >= 8:
        Output.extend(newarray)
save(Output, 'outputfilename')
```

This output is a much shorter and more workable array. But my understanding is that this is incredibly inefficient (We're looping through a million row array a million times, that's a trillion calls, that seems problematic.)

Were this data in a database, I could grab it with:

`SELECT * FROM array WHERE col_1 = i AND COUNT(i) >= 8`

(depending on which SQL this might take a different form).

So far as I can tell, neither Python nor numpy has built-in functions that act like this. I don't expect the language to parse a SQL query, but there must be *some* tool within the language that approximates this function.

Numpy has a `select` method that doesn't actually select rows in this way, and some other methods that sound like they might make these operations possible but seem to do nothing of the sort. As mentioned below, the documentation is very thin on examples.

---

I have seen things somewhat like this done using `collections.Counter()`, but I'm not sure this specific desire can be done with it and am uncertain how to do it. The documentation is... thin on examples.

I'm aware of the fact that this may be an XY question, and have hence attempted to leave out the X except as examples of what I've tried. I am, however, in need of tools using Python (via SageMath/Jupyter). If there's a way of directly storing numpy/Python data in a database-like format and hitting it with SQL-like queries, that would be great too.

Comment: It's unclear and unspecific. See [ask]. Are you asking for a scheme such as converting data one time to optimize for multiple searches? For that, why not using a ```dict``` or B-tree?

Comment: @relent95 I'm surprised you feel it's unclear. Is there something in particular missing? I can expand the example to be more specific I suppose. --- If such a one-time conversion does the trick, I'm up for it, again trying to not assume an X to the Y. --- I will look into `dict` though I worry that examples will be thin on the ground; I assume "B-tree" is for "binary tree"? This is the point where I say that my formal CS education ended with Fortran 90 in 1995. I *vaguely* recall discussing sort algorithms. Everything since has been self-taught, from PHP/mySQL to some C# to Python/SageMath.

Comment: SO is not for discussion. Opinions should be avoided. If you don't want to define your problem with an exact scope, post on another forum.

Comment: I've added a much more detailed version of the problem, at least I think so. I'm also uncertain what you mean about 'not for discussion'; is not the general format 'ask question; get an answer, or possibly several, depending on whether the community thinks multiple answers might allow flexibility'? --- I'll admit I'm coming from mostly math.stackexchange, so norms will be different, but I thought I'd presented a pretty clear question. Anyway, hopefully the extension and clarification help.

Comment: I mean 'unclear and unspecific' for a scenario, an environment, conditions, etc., under which your code will run, not for a data format. I guess you are looking for a fancy magic that doesn't exist in the view point of a software engineer. Using a database(RDBMS), you need to create an index to optimize such queries. If you don't do that, it will iterate rows sequentially, in pretty much the same way as your example for loop, in principle.

Comment: @relent95 Environment was specified as Python/Sagemath/Jupyter. The scenario is... exactly as presented? --- You mention creating an index; is that something the `dict` method (set of methods) will help with? Because if so, I suppose that's at least part of the answer I needed :)

Answer (score 1):

This might not be exactly what you are looking for, but I hope it can be helpful either way. :) I wrote a loop implementation that should be more efficient than the one you provided since we only loop through the column twice. We use a dictionary to keep track of the number of times a specific value in the first column occurs.

```py
countDict = {} 

#Counting the number of times a sum occurs in the first column of the array
for row in array:
    
    if row[0] in countDict:
       #If row sum exists in dictionary we increment the count
        countDict[row[0]] +=1
    else:
        #Else we add the first count (1)
        countDict[row[0]] = 1
        

output = [] #Output to generate

#Loop through first column of array again
for row in array:
    
    #If the sum value occured at least 8 times we add it to the output list
    if countDict[row[0]] >= 8:
        output.append(row)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll see what I can do with this. Now I guess a follow-up question is, is this something that could be done using `dict` as suggested above?

Comment: @Eric Synder, the ```dict``` is a Python type. ```countDict = {}``` is equivalent to ```countDict = dict()```. Yes it's a good example of using ```dict``` for optimization.

Comment: @EricSnyder Yes, as was mentioned and explained by relent95 above, it is already using the dict as was suggested to you in comments above. The dict, or dictionary, basically associates a key with a value, and that value can (most of the time) be accessed with the key in a really efficient way by the computer. That is why we can keep track off the counts of each value in column 1 without having extended run times. I ran a test and for an array with 2 million rows it took my computer 1.3 seconds to run the code, so I think it should be efficient enough to be useful. :)